# C# port to Linux Mono or .NET Core

Tags: c#, linux, wcf, mono, .net-core

I have a service written in C# for Windows. I need to get it to run on Linux. I've looked at potentially rewriting the code in either Java or C++, and I likely will do that down the road, but as an intermediate solution I'm looking at porting the project to Mono or .NET Core. The key is that it's a fairly small application, so making the necessary code changes shouldn't be too much work.

The service listens to specific URL endpoints to performs tasks.

Examples based on code sample below:

http://localhost:5000/checkStatus?configId=1234

http://localhost:5000/echo

http://localhost:5000/version

In fact, I nearly have it compiling expect for this section. This one section is generating all of my remaining build errors. I understand that WCF services are not yet available in .NET Core. So I've been exploring alternatives to this but I'm having a hard time with what will work on Linux in .NET Core. I also want to avoid implementing something that would be tantamount to rewriting the entire thing or shoehorning in a full NGINX or Apache server.

```
namespace CheckService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string checkStatus(string configId);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string echo(string value);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string version();
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely familiar with WCF either as I've never worked with it and this project was originally written by someone else.

Here's my project.json. I'm aware I might have some unnecessary or incorrect items in there. I've been testing a lot:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies" : {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "ServiceStack": "4.5.4",
    "System": "4.1.311.2",
    "System.IO": "4.3.0",
    "System.IO.Pipes": "4.0.0",
    "System.Collections": "4.0.11",
    "System.Data.Common": "4.0.0",
    "System.Data.SQLite": "1.0.0",
    "System.ServiceModel": "1.0.0",
    "System.ServiceModel.Web": "1.0.0",
    "System.ServiceModel.Primitives": "4.3.0",
    "System.ServiceModel.Security": "3.9.0",
    "System.ServiceModel.Http": "4.0.0",
    "slf4net.log4net": "0.1.32.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
  }
}
```

Is there another way I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the `WebGetAttribute` indicates that you intend to create a RESTful service. While WCF is not available in .NET Core,  WebApi is supported. With WebApi you can create REST Services, which might be all you need. You can check [this tutorial by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) on how to get started with this.

Comment: Thanks, I think this might be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run ServiceStack on .NET Core you should be referencing the `1.0.*` ServiceStack packages as indicated in [ServiceStack's .NET Core Release Notes](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2#referencing-net-core-packages):

```
"dependencies" : {
  "ServiceStack.Core": "1.0.*",
  "ServiceStack.Common.Core": "1.0.*",
  "ServiceStack.Client.Core": "1.0.*",
  "ServiceStack.Interfaces.Core": "1.0.*",
  "ServiceStack.Text.Core": "1.0.*"
},
```

Or if you're not using https://servicestack.net you should remove the reference to "ServiceStack" in your project.json.

Comment: Thanks. I was just experimenting with ServiceStack at one point. I neglected to remove the reference.